# PHP GNUPG - decrypt failed

Tags: php, gnupg

I want to decrypt the text using GPG but getting an error **"decrypt failed"** The code is as below

```
putenv('GNUPGHOME=/home/USERNAME>/.gnupg');
$payload = '<ENCRYPTED_TEXT>';
$initGnupg = gnupg_init();
gnupg_adddecryptkey($initGnupg,"<FINGERPRINT>", '<PASSPHRASE>');
$decryptedPayload = gnupg_decrypt($initGnupg, $payload);
echo gnupg_geterror($initGnupg);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($decryptedPayload);
```